# Delay action unless user scrolls

Tags: jquery

I want to show a div for 6 seconds unless the user scrolls, which will instead automatically hide the div. Currently I have this

```
  var wasScrolled = false;

 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    wasScrolled = true;
    hideBasketballs();
  });

  hideBasketballs();

  function hideBasketballs() {
      if(wasScrolled === false) {
        $(".basketballs").delay(6000).slideUp();
      } else {
        $(".basketballs").slideUp();
      }
  }
```

This did not work as I expected, instead the div always waits for the 6 seconds, and does not slide up if the user scrolls.

I also simply tried this:

```
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $(".basketballs").slideUp();
  });

  $(".basketballs").delay(6000).slideUp();
```

But I have the same issue, any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

```
  var wasScrolled = false;

  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    wasScrolled = true;
    hideBasketballs();
  });

  hideBasketballs();

  function hideBasketballs() {
      if(wasScrolled === false) {
        setTimeout(function() {
             $('.basketballs').slideUp();
        }, 6000);
      } else {
        $(".basketballs").slideUp();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try adding a setTimeout of 6 seconds which checks if wasScrolled is still false, then calls the slideup, instead of using .delay ? Maybe calling the immediate slideUp on an element that has a delay action set to it doesn't work